How to request for a software package to be updated in Debian unstable and testing?
This is a sister question of How to request for a software package to be updated in OpenSUSE?
I am a maintainer of safeeyes, which is broken in Debian Testing (Trixie) due to incompatibility with python3.12, which has been fixed in the latest version of the package.
However, both Debian Unstable and Testing host older versions.
How to ask the Debian packagers to update the package?
Note: I know that Debian usually does not update its packages after package freeze, but AFAIK, it has not happened in Trixie yet.

In general, requesting a newer version of a package in Debian is done by filing a wishlist bug on it. In most cases this isn’t necessary, because most packages in Debian track new releases; you can see this on the safeeyes tracker — it indicates that 2.2.1 is available. If the package isn’t updated in unstable after a reasonable amount of time, filing a bug can serve as a useful reminder to the maintainer (and an indication that there is interest in getting an updated version in Debian).
In this specific instance, filing a bug is warranted if the package can’t work with Python 3.12 anyway; since Python 3.12 is now the default in testing and unstable, such a bug can be filed as a grave bug, not just wishlist — the bug is that the package doesn’t work with the default Python interpreter, which is a grave bug, and it happens to be fixed by upgrading to a newer upstream release.
If you have a Debian system, you can do this by running
reportbug safeeyes

and following the prompts. reportbug will show existing bugs filed on the package; you should check that a similar bug hasn’t already been filed.
If you don’t, check that there isn’t a similar bug in the bug tracker, and if appropriate, send an email to submit@bugs.debian.org, and start the email with “pseudo-headers” indicating the package and severity:
Package: safeeyes
Severity: wishlist

